# How to route data from Azure IoT Hub to Blob and Time Series Insights

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-iot-hub, azure-timeseries-insights

I'm trying to route telemetry data from Azure IoT Hub to Azure Time Series Insights for mid term storage and visualization and to Azure Blob Storage for long term storage.

I created a new consumer group for timeseriesinsights on the IoT Hub and added an IoT Hub Event Source pointing to this consumer group on TimeSeries Insights.
So far data is routed to Time Series Insights.

When I add a custom route and a blob endpoint for all telemetry (query = true) to Azure IoT Hub the Time Series Insights Event source seems to break, so that now longer data is stored in time series insights.

The only solution I currently see is to forward data from IoT Hob to an event hub and there use event hub capture to store the data to the blob and connect an Time Series Insights Event Source to the Event hub.

1. Is anybody else having the same problem?
2. Is there a better solution without the eventhub in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have two routes such as:

1. query = true for blob storage
2. query = true for **events** (that's the built-in default endpoint)